# I would like to perform a cloth simulation by combining two or more different cloths

Tags: cloth-simulation

Thank you for finding my question.
I'm Japanese and I'm not good at English, so please allow me to post using Google Translate.

Production environment:
macOS Sonoma
Blender4.0

As the title suggests, I would like to create a cloth simulation by combining two or more different cloths (Command+J).

I made a blanket with frills.
I finally solved this problem by sewing the ruffle onto the blanket, but I'm looking for other solutions.
For example, you might want to give the texture of a different fabric to a ruffle or blanket, or add another fabric fabric embellishment, such as a ribbon.
You may also want to add seam objects.

Combining them with Command + J to perform a cloth simulation will separate the objects.
I would like to perform a cloth simulation where objects follow without separating. Is there any other way other than sutures?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, if the meshes are separated they will separate when the simulation will play, make sure that the pieces are joined by faces

Answer (score 1):

If we use cloth on disconnected geometry, there won't be any forces created to hold the geo together:

[image]

We could connect the geometry (right) or use sewing lines (left):

[image]

But sewing lines won't create any bending forces and won't play nicely with some other modifiers.  And connecting the geometry change your rendering geometry, in a way that is likely not going to be what you want for future subdivision:

[image]

There are some things we could probably do to help this, using GN to mask away some geometry between the physics and other modifiers.  But the fool-proof method of dealing with needing one topology for physics and a different topology for rendering is to use two different meshes:

[image]

By surface or mesh deforming from a physics mesh to a rendering mesh, you can use a different topology for your cloth and your rendering mesh, tuning the topology to the needs of each.  Your physics pillow can be a single mesh while your rendering object is two separate meshes.